# iPhone - Leaks in MessageUI framework?

Tags: iphone, email, messageui

I use **MFMailComposeViewController** to send emails in my app.
When I run my app with **Instruments**,
I see a leak after I tapped to send the email.

```
Leaked Object   #   Address Size    Responsible Library Responsible Frame

MutableMessageHeaders,1 0x6be950    32 Bytes    MessageUI   +[MFComposeTypeFactory headersFromDelegate:]

_MFOutgoingMessageBody,1    0x1190ed0   32 Bytes    Message -[MessageWriter createMessageWithPlainTextDocumentsAndAttachments:headers:]
```

Do you know how to fix it,
is this a leak in MessageUI framework?

```
- (void)showMailComposer
{
        MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [picker setSubject:@"Subject"];
        NSString *emailBody = @"Email body";
        [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];
        [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
        [picker release];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Dismiss Mail/SMS view controller

    // Dismisses the email composition interface when users tap Cancel or Send. Proceeds to update the 
    // message field with the result of the operation.
    - (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller 
              didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error 
{
            [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, looks like it. But at a total of 64 bytes per sent email, it’s not one you should be worried about.

Comment: Hate to be a snoot.  But, that seems to be popular opinion...And I see the rate of memory leaking increase with each OS update.  All this really means is the user has to restart their phone more often.  At the same time Apple tells us to take every effort to make the user experience that much better...hmmm.